# Power query; how do i bring the value for one column in the previous row, or column in the next row, while matching criteria in current row columns?

Tags: time, powerbi, powerquery, calculated-columns

I have a table with many columns, there is a row for every interaction happening where the case changes from person to person (or queue); example below:

[image]

I am attempting to get the time a case was with an agent, or in a queue.
to do this, i need help in bringing in the date stamp in the next instance where a case changes owner, and do the time calculation between the "interaction createdDate" from the next interaction and current . I need a final table to look like image below:
[image]

is there a way to do this in powerquery without duplicating and indexing the tables? or Dax that i would use to say:
If next row matches caseID get "Interaction CreatedDate" from next row,  and then i can do the calculation to tell me the time spent with current owner in the row?

Answer (score 0):

With some effortless work i got it to work :)
i made sure my source data in the model was sorted correctly as shown in the illustration above.
and then i added an index column.
[image]

Next I ran the query and applied the following Dax in the table .

if(

'TableName'[CaseId] =
LOOKUPVALUE( 'TableName'[CaseId] , 'TableName'[Index] , 'TableName'[Index]  +1),
LOOKUPVALUE( 'TableName'[CreatedDate] ,'TableName'[Index] , 'TableName'[Index]  +1)

)

hope this finds its way to someone who needs it :)